# How to Handle ASP page redirect with Python and Mechanize

Tags: python, asp.net, redirect, mechanize

I have used Python, mechanize, and Beautiful Soup, to traverse a few pages at our University's library room booking page which can be found here

```
https://rooms.library.dc-uoit.ca/uoit_studyrooms/calendar.aspx
```

I created a browser with mechanize, followed one of the two available dates listed on the above page, and it brings up a table of bookable times. If The cell is "Open" then it has a link of the following form:

```
href= 'temp.aspx?starttime=8:00 AM&amp;room=LIB305&amp;next=book.aspx'
```

When I click that link in a normal browser window it redirects me to this page:

```
https://rooms.library.dc-uoit.ca/uoit_studyrooms/book.aspx
```

However when I use the mechanize browser instance to open it, I am redirected back to the original page. I am using the same instance of the browser the whole way through and the cookies don't seem to change (there's only 1 I can see). Im not sure why I am not being redirected to the proper page. Any hints?